# What is the function/code in R shiny that is used to calculate math operations?

Tags: r, shiny, graphics, dataset, calculation

How to perform mathematical operations on variables in the input dataset? For example, I input a table with assets and debt variables (each variable has more than one data), then I want to divide all data in the assets variable and all data in the liabilities variable. How is the coding to perform that operation? I've looked at various sources but haven't found the right one.

This is the code I have made:

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(


  tabsetPanel(

    tabPanel("Input Data",

             br(),

             fileInput("simpan_file", "Choose CSV File",
                       accept = c(
                         "text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")
      
             ), 
             radioButtons("pemisah", "Separator",
                          choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                      Semicolon = ";",
                                      Tab = "\t"),
                          selected = ",", inline = TRUE),
             br(),
             br(), br(), 
             
             DTOutput("print_data"),
             tableOutput("simpan_file")),
    
    tabPanel("Earning per Share",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("variable1", "Variabel 1", choices = NULL),
                 selectInput("variable2", "Variabel 2", choices = NULL),
                 actionButton("calculateBtn", "Hitung")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("linePlot")
               )
             
             )    )))
```

## server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session)

{output$print_data <- renderDT(
{

    simpan_file <- input$simpan_file

    if (is.null(simpan_file))

      return(NULL)

    read.csv(simpan_file$datapath, sep = input$pemisah)}) 

  earnings <- reactive({

    req(input$calculateBtn, data())

    variable1 <- input$variable1
    variable2 <- input$variable2

    if (!is.null(variable1) && !is.null(variable2)) {
      earnings <- divide_variables(data(), variable1, variable2)
      return(earnings)
    }})output$dataTable <- renderTable({
    data()})  output$linePlot <- renderPlot({
    req(earnings())
    
    ggplot(data = data(), aes(x = rownames(data()), y = earnings())) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(x = "Data Point", y = "Earning per Share") +
      theme_minimal() }) 

data <- reactive(
{ 

req(input$loadBtn)
    inFile <- input$file


    if (!is.null(inFile)) {
      data <- read_excel_data(inFile$datapath)
      updateSelectInput(session, "variable1", choices = colnames(data))
      updateSelectInput(session, "variable2", choices = colnames(data))
      return(data)
    }})}
```

The problem with the code that I made is that it cannot display the dataset variables in the second tabpanel, and there is no code for the mathematical operations.
What I'm expecting is that the website can divide the two variables in the dataset and then display the result in the form of a line chart in the main panel.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'm sorry to say that I don't understand your question.  The code you use to "divide variables" (what does that mean?) in Shiny is exactly the same as it would be oustide of Shiny.  And without data to test your program, it's difficult to give concrete advice.  We need both test input data and your expected output based on that data.  Where is your `divide_variables` function defined? You may find this link on on standard evaluation ([NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)) helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing sentence (english is not my first language). I mean the code for 'Variable 1 : variable 2' in the dataset, it is like '6 : 2 = 3'

Comment: If you have columns `x` and `y` in your data frame, then `df$z <- df$x / df$y` will produce a column `z` whose elements are the corresponding elements of `x` divided by the corresponding elements of `y`.  So if `x <- c(6, 3)`  and `y <- c(3, 3)`,  `z` will be `c(2, 1)`.   If that doesn't answer your question, please supply the additional information I requested earlier.